# Keras model compiles fine, yet fails when training with InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model compiles fine, but it fails when I start training:

`InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,28,28,728] vs. shape[1] = [1,0,0,256]
         [[Node: upblock3_concat/concat = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](block4_sepconv2_bn_1/cond/Merge, upblock3_crop/strided_slice, upblock3_concat/concat/axis)]]
         [[Node: metrics/iou/Mean/_2825 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_17728_metrics/iou/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
Caused by op 'upblock3_concat/concat', defined at:
  File "cranes/train.py", line 134, in <module>
    fire.Fire(train)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 127, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, context, name)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 366, in _Fire
    component, remaining_args)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 542, in _CallCallable
    result = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "cranes/train.py", line 48, in train
    model = XUnet(xception_weights=None)((target_size, target_size, 3))
  File "/home/karolzak/ric/hackathon-prague-2018/cranes/xunet.py", line 157, in __call__
    x = layers.Concatenate(name=prefix + 'concat')([bridge, x])
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 619, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 155, in call
    return self._merge_function(inputs)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/merge.py", line 357, in _merge_function
    return K.concatenate(inputs, axis=self.axis)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1881, in concatenate
    return tf.concat([to_dense(x) for x in tensors], axis)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1099, in concat
    return gen_array_ops._concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 706, in _concat_v2
    "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/karolzak/.local/share/virtualenvs/hackathon-prague-2018-Ywp4garX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,28,28,728] vs. shape[1] = [1,0,0,256]
         [[Node: upblock3_concat/concat = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](block4_sepconv2_bn_1/cond/Merge, upblock3_crop/strided_slice, upblock3_concat/concat/axis)]]
         [[Node: metrics/iou/Mean/_2825 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_17728_metrics/iou/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]`

My code is quite complicated, but the interesting part is

```
bridge = SeparableConv2D(728, (3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False, name='block4_sepconv2')(bridge)

# lots of things happening here

x = Cropping2D(cropping=(padding, padding), name=prefix + 'crop')(x)

x = layers.Concatenate(name=prefix + 'concat')([bridge, x])
```

If I open an interpreter right before `layers.Concatenate` it seems the shapes *should* match:

```
In [1]: x
Out[1]: <tf.Tensor 'upblock3_crop/strided_slice:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 256) dtype=float32>

In [2]: bridge
Out[2]: <tf.Tensor 'block4_sepconv2_bn_1/cond/Merge:0' shape=(?, 28, 28, 728) dtype=float32>

In [3]: K.int_shape(x)
Out[3]: (None, 28, 28, 256)

In [4]: K.int_shape(bridge)
Out[4]: (None, 28, 28, 728)
```

What is going on here? Any ideas how to debug this? If that makes a difference, I am using TensorFlow 1.4.0 and Keras 2.1.5.

UPDATE: model summary https://gist.github.com/ryszard/ad484ca39c8b650c72693d91b3abcbb8 (it's too long to paste in the body of the question).

UPDATE 2:

I changed my code to be:

```
        x = Cropping2D(cropping=(padding, padding), name=prefix + 'crop')(x)
        x_shape = K.int_shape(x)
        #x = layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (-1,) + x_shape[1:]))(x)
        print('reshaping', x_shape[1:])
        x = layers.Reshape(x_shape[1:])(x)
        print('right before', K.int_shape(bridge), K.int_shape(x))
        x = layers.Concatenate(name=prefix + 'concat')([bridge, x])
```

In that version, I get

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 0 values, but the requested shape has 200704
         [[Node: reshape_1/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](upblock3_crop/strided_slice, reshape_1/Reshape/shape)]]
         [[Node: metrics/acc/Mean_1/_2821 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_17769_metrics/acc/Mean_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

If I do the reshape with the lambda (commented in the snippet) instead, I get:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,28,28,728] vs. shape[1] = [0,28,28,256]
         [[Node: upblock3_concat/concat = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](block4_sepconv2_bn_1/cond/Merge, reshape_1/Reshape, upblock3_concat/concat/axis)]]
         [[Node: metrics/iou/Mean/_2825 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_17782_metrics/iou/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

If it's `layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x, (1,) + x_shape[1:]))(x)`, then Keras complains:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 28, 28, 728), (1, 28, 28, 256)]
```

Comment: what does your model.summary() say?

Comment: I updated the question: https://gist.github.com/ryszard/ad484ca39c8b650c72693d91b3abcbb8. Yes, I am doing something that's probably too complicated for my own good.

Comment: The inputs to your concat layer have incompatible shapes. You need to figure out why (probably different number of output channels or something) and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example works. I do have Tensorflow 1.6, I have to add, not sure if that makes a difference. Please test this in your computer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as K
from keras.layers import *

prefix = 'test'
img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 784))
bridge = SeparableConv2D(728, (3, 3), padding='valid', use_bias=False, name='block4_sepconv2')( img )
padding = 1
x = Cropping2D( cropping=( padding, padding ), name= prefix + 'crop')( img )
print ( x )
print( x.get_shape(), K.int_shape( x ) )
x = Concatenate(name=prefix + 'concat')([ bridge, x ])
print ( x )
print( x.get_shape(), K.int_shape( x ) )
```

> Tensor("testcrop/strided_slice:0", shape=(?, 30, 30, 784), dtype=float32)
>   (TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(30), Dimension(30), Dimension(784)]), (None, 30, 30, 784))
>
> Tensor("testconcat/concat:0", shape=(?, 30, 30, 1512), dtype=float32)
>   (TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(30), Dimension(30), Dimension(1512)]), (None, 30, 30, 1512))

If this example doesn't work for you, upgrade your tensorflow. If it does, we will have to examine how you get to the value of x with the undetermined H and W sizes.

Comment: reshaping kinda helped (in the sense that I am getting slightly different results), see my update. But still no ball :/

Comment: It does work:

Using TensorFlow backend.
Tensor("testcrop/strided_slice:0", shape=(?, 30, 30, 784), dtype=float32)
(?, 30, 30, 784) (None, 30, 30, 784)
Tensor("testconcat/concat:0", shape=(?, 30, 30, 1512), dtype=float32)
(?, 30, 30, 1512) (None, 30, 30, 1512)

Comment: Ok then the problem is in the section `# lots of things happening here`. You need to share the operations that lead to the value of x before the cropping.